# Spring Boot Shell Security

Tags: shell, security, spring-boot

Trying to change the default security for using the CRaSH Shell, but getting an exception 
The Reference manual says the following

> You can use the **shell.auth.simple.username** and **shell.auth.simple.password** properties to configure custom connection credentials.

But I get the below exception after I put those two properties in the application.properties file. I have something like :

```
shell.auth.simple.username=foo-user
shell.auth.simple.password=foo-pwd
```

This gives the following exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'username' of bean class [org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.ShellProperties$SimpleAuthenticationProperties]: Bean property 'username' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the list of properties](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html) use

```
shell.auth.simple.user.name=
shell.auth.simple.user.password=
```

This also matches the path as used in the code. I suspect [the docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-remote-shell.html#production-ready-remote-shell-credentials) haven't been updated properly.